# What is device_authorization_endpoint in spring authorization server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-authorization-server

while working with spring authorization server, I came across "device_authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth2/device_authorization"
Can any one let me know what it is?

And also Jwks Uri endpoint, "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:9000/auth/oauth2/jwks" what it is and why it is used?

Answer (score 0):

Both APIs are part of the oAuth2 protocol that are migrated to spring framework.
For deeply understanding, first you have to understand the oAuth protocol and its features then understand their implementation in the spring framework.

The device_authorization allows devices with limited data input to get the privilege to access the resources.

The JWKS is used to get JWT(Json Web Token) which is the key that is used to get access to resources under the JWS(Json Web Signature) specification.